# Toon Shader Materials Appear Pink in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp, unity3d-shaders, materials

I am working on a project in Unity which was created using the **Universal Render Pipeline (URP)** project template. I have imported this asset pack from the Unity Asset Store -> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/animals/quirky-series-free-animals-pack-178235

When I opened up the demo scene, I found that all the materials were pink.

[image]

The materials use a **Toon/SoftSurface** Shader.

In the Edit > Project Settings > Graphics, there is a **URP** asset selected for the render pipeline:

[image]

The **Toon/SoftSurface** shader does not appear under **URP:**
[image]

Going to

> Edit > Rendering > Materials > Convert Selected Materials to URP.

This message pops up:

[image]

I have also tried

> Window > Rendering > Render Pipeline Converter

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Currently using Unity Editor version 2022.3.10f1

Comment: then it would suggest its not URP compatible.. sometimes the people include a unity package to overwrite the materials with URP friendly ones.

Comment: In the description for the asset pack it says that it is URP compatible

Comment: and even on the asset store i see a URP shader graph to use to replace the softtoon shader.. did you do that? Doesnt necessarily come under Toon btw

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that was it, I'm just after finding the instructions on their website :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not compatible, so I prepared a DEMO on how to convert them manually.

1. You need to find the *Materials* folder.
2. There you select all materials and in the inspector panel you want to change the shader to `Universal render pipeline > Lit`
3. Then every material one by one needs to manually link the texture.
4. When a material is selected go to the *Textures* folder, where you find a texture with the same name as the material (M_Colobus = T_Colobus)
5. Drag the material to the *Base Map* field in material view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the developers website, I've just discovered that they have instructions on how to resolve the issue: https://www.omabuarts.com/urp-for-quirky-series/

By selecting the materials and changing the shader slot to Shader Graph > SoftSurfaceGraph, the materials are fixed!

Comment: so exactly what i said then